# bootstrap select2 results won't show on return

Tags: ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use bootstrap select2(ajax) in my custom joomla component but I don not get my data to be listed on return. The javascript looks as it follows

```
jQuery("#e6").select2({
    placeholder: "PLZ // Bundesland // Ort angeben",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: { 
        url: "index.php?option=com_tieraerzte&task=tieraerzt.locator&tmpl=component",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                q: term, // search term
            };
        },
        results: function(data, page) {               
            return {results: data};
        }
    },
    formatResult: function(data) {
        //shows undefined on return
        alert(data.plz);
        return "<div class='select2-user-result'>" + data.plz + "</div>";
    },
    formatSelection: function(data) {
        return data.plz;
    }
});
```

snipet of returned json data

```
[[{"plz":"10247","kiez":"Friedrichshain-Kreuzberg","ort":"Berlin","bundesland":"Berlin"}]]
```